# Print in bytes with "du"

Tags: bash, filesize, du

I am using `du -sh` to see the size of directories. If I check a 1KiB directory, I will see:

```
1.0K    .
```

However, I want the output in bytes, and *only* the bytecount.

For example:

```
$ du -sh .
1024
```

Comment: Why are you using the `h` flag then? Read the man page.

Comment: Mat, if I omit `h` I do not get a byte count. For example, an 8K directory gives me `16` without `-h`. 8 kilobytes is not 16 bytes.

Comment: The command `du` stands for _disk usage_, i.e. how much space does this file/directory use on disk (sectors, etc). It does not stand for _how many bytes are stored in the file_, but more _how many bytes are needed to store a file of N Bytes of content_. The pure byte count is done with `du -b`. See [I'm confused by the output of `du`](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/16/confused-by-the-output-of-du-in-linux/)

Comment: Thank you kvantour. This only works on GNU `du`, but that is okay. I also piped through `grep -o '^[0-9]\+'` to get the true output I needed

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To get size in bytes you should use command on this way:

```
du -sb
```

(this `b` mean bytes)

for the `du` which do not work properly with `-b` you can use

```
du -s --block-size=1
```

Comment: It does not. "b" is equivalent to "--apparent-size --block-size=1" and will give you apparent size is bytes (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html)

Comment: @sergiz, `--block-size=1` mean in bytes. As `--block-size=1k`==`-k`

Comment: Your comment is the correct answer since using "-b" will give you apparent size.